# Как сохранить полученный byte код изображения?

Tags: java

1) Нужно получить байт код картинки и сохранить его.

2) Полученный byte-код вставить в код программы "в виде строки".

3) Из записанного byte-кода создать изображение.

Проблема в том, что не получается сохранить байт код (если записывать в txt, то он конвертируется и его больше невозможно использовать).

```
package image;
```

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageTest {

```
private static OutputStream txt;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        byte[] imageInByte;
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("e:/darksouls.jpg"));

        // конвертация изображения в массив байтов
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();

        // конвертация массива байтов в изображение
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
        txt = new FileOutputStream("e:/dark.svg"); //запись массива байтов в файл1
        txt.write(imageInByte);
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File("e:/new-darksouls.svg"));//запись массива байтов в файл2

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}
Данная программа конвертирует изображение в массив байтов, и создает из этого массива новое изображение.

Как сохранить этот массив байтов, чтобы создавать изображения используя один байт-код(не обращаясь к исходному изображению)?

Comment: Зачем вы делаете столько лишних движений и перекодирований?

Вы можете работать с исходным файлом `e:/darksouls.jpg` как с набором байт. Вам не надо загружать изображение и потом сохранять его чтобы получить набор байт - вам надо просто прочитать набор байт из файла.

Answer (score 1):

2) Полученный byte-код вставить в код программы "в виде строки".
Это не возможно, что по сути String в java, это набор char[] сохраненный в определенной кодировке(в char хранят обычно символы юникода, он для этого и придуман). П.с картинка это набор нейких байтов(ну пускай char) которые при переводе в юникод попросту повреждаются.

И не понятно что вы хотите сделать?

```
byte[] imageInByte; -> нейкий набор байтов
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("e:/darksouls.jpg")); -> ну допустим

        // convert BufferedImage to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // динамичный набор байтов, ок
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos); //?
        baos.flush(); //? очистить? зачем тогда заполняли его че-то не то а?
```

"используя один байт-код" ??

1.Сохранить изображение? в файл, имея набор байтов изображения, ок

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("буква c че-то там.jpg");
file.write(ваш набор байтов);
file.close(); //обязательно закрыть файл
```

Comment: Денис, проблема в том, что у меня нет набора байтов. 

Я могу получить массив байтов и хранить его в буфере, но не удается сохранить в виде байт кода (кодируется), что бы как то вставить его в эту строку:
"file.write(ваш набор байтов);"

Comment: И опять же, как сохранить полученный byte код изображения, чтобы при необходимости можно было его копировать?)

Comment: Можно посмотреть код картинки используя Far Manager (шестнадцатеричный код) и уже его копировать и вставлять сюда: "file.write(ваш набор байтов);". Но скорей всего он запишется как текст (символьный массив).

Comment: Надо использовать SVG. SVG - это XML, а XML это, как известно, текст. Копируй, вставляй куда хочешь, как хочешь.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov svg не открывается, но если его переименовать в jpg, то картинка откроется. (Код создания svg файлов написал в главном сообщении).

Comment: Не думаю, что SVG следует обрабатывать как Image, это же XML. Для работы с SVG есть специальные библиотеки, например [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)

Answer (score 0):

С охранить изображение в "виде строки" можно используя перекодирование его в BASE64 и обратно либо использовать формат изображения SVG.

Comment: Что в этом ответе не так?

Comment: Перекодирование его в BASE64 - вариант. Не подскажите, как называется необходимая библиотека и где ее взять?

Из формата SVG в ручную не получается скопировать байт код.

Comment: Если у вас 8-я Java, то в ней есть стандартный класс [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). Для более ранних версий можно использовать из [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) класс [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). Странно что у вас не получается с SVG - это же практически XML, см. [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG)

Comment: "Надо использовать SVG. SVG - это XML, а XML это, как известно, текст. Копируй, вставляй куда хочешь, как хочешь."

Ошибка при открытии файла (через браузер):
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
И опять же, если я открою код он будет отображаться уже не в исходном виде.

Comment: Я не понимаю вашей конечной цели. Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? Для отображения в броузере необходимо svg "завернуть" в html, как в прочем и любой другой файл отличный от html, ведь броузер рассчитан на просмотр именно html, а не чего-нибуь другого. Для просмотра  графических файлов обычно используют специальные программы. По поводу svg в html можно посмотреть здесь [Embed SVG Directly Into HTML Pages](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp)

Comment: Конечная цель - одна прога.exe (у которой нет корневой папки с файлами), которая создает фотографии без дополнительных файлов.